# How can I change the title for the export of a heading in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am creating a document by exporting a specific heading via `C-c C-e C-s`. I want to specify a title for that exported doc (which is not the text of the heading). I also want to be able to export a parent heading or the whole doc, and in that case I just want the heading to be what it would be without setting a title.

Can I do this somehow, perhaps by setting a particular property?

Comment: Does @Lgen's answer achieve what you want?  If so, could you please accept it?

Comment: It works — I somehow missed the the original notification, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use an `:EXPORT_TITLE:` property as follows:

```
 * Heading to be exported with C-c C-e C-s...
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EXPORT_TITLE: Title of the document when subtree is exported 
   :END:
```

Some other properties can be useful:

`:EXPORT_DATE:` `:EXPORT_AUTHOR:` `:EXPORT_TITLE:` `:EXPORT_OPTIONS:` `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:`

They are discussed at the end of the [Export Settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings) section of Org manual.

Comment: Is it possible to export a long title in two lines? According to the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-settings) that works with `#+TITLE:` but it is not working with two `:EXPORT_TITLE:` lines... :-(. Incidentally, I am trying to clone a word template, and so the export is into ODT.